# Validate if a value is already in a column from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi ive tried to create a code so  the user from cant insert the same id in the table, so ive created an insert button that validates it before he actually inserts something , but for some reason it isnt working, please help me(im new to VBA):

Heres my code:

```
Sub Insert()

'
' insert Macro
'
Dim row As Double, search As String
row = 5
search = ""

Do

row = row + 1

  If Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Value = Data.Cells(row, 1).Value Then GoTo Error
  If Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Value <> Data.Cells(row, 1).Value Then GoTo Insert
   Exit Do
 
Loop Until Data.Cells(row, 1).Value = ""


Error:
    search = "Ok"
     MsgBox "Id already exists", vbExclamation,"Error"
  Exit Sub
  
Insert:

 If IsEmpty(Range("I17")) Or IsEmpty(Range("D11")) and search ="" Then
    MsgBox "all the fields must be filled", vbExclamation
  Else:
  ' heres the  code to insert values from sheet1  to sheet2
  
  End If
  Exit Sub
```

For some reason its not looping its only validating if the value found in  the first row of the table from the other sheet(Data), which is the row 6. Both cell from sheet1 and the column from Data are converted to Numbers Format(exactly the same).

Heres the Id the user insert which im trying to validate ID being I17 cell(sheet name being Form):
[image]

**Ps: if u need more info let me know**

And here is the field im trying to lookin if the value matchs(Data Sheet):

[image]

Comment: This is because on your first Row it doesnt match, and you are telling it to `GoTo Insert`, which takes it outside the loop and you never return back to the loop.

Comment: But when i try to remove the second condition it nevers goes to the insert function, it always finds a match even though there isnt one. i tested it the way ur speaking. But still doesnt work =(

Comment: i could post the debug print values with an non-existant id without the the second condition to get it clearer, also im accepting any other way of doing this. I feel like im missing a catch =(

Comment: 1/ That's because the code is very confusing (to you). If you break it down line by line this is what is doing: Set row as 5, set search as empty string, Start Do, add 1 to row, check if Row 6, column 1 is equal to Row 17, column 9. If Equal goto Error, (in this Error step you make Search = "ok" then you provide a Message Box saying it Exists and then you END THE SUB" you never used "search" for anything at this point and the sub has ended, nothing else will happen.

Comment: 2/ If the value is not Equal, then goto Insert. (In this Insert step you check if Search is Empty, if Range I17 is empty, or if Range D11 is empty, if so then you provide a message that "All fields are filled", then you NEVER return back to the Do Loop, so your Sub ends also here. Nothing else happens. Instead of using GoTo, you should make your IF Checks inside the Do Loop without END SUB so it will continue looping.

Comment: u mean inserting all the code inside the loop? Sorry im quite new to vba and its my first programming language

Comment: Also u mean exit sub or end sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I do not know exactly what you are trying to do, this is the simplest way to get you started.

```
Sub Insert()
'
' insert Macro
'
    Dim row As Double, search As String
    row = 5
    search = ""

Do
    row = row + 1

    If Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Value = Data.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
        'What to do if the value matched Goes Here
        MsgBox "Id already exists on Data in Row: " & row, vbExclamation,"Error"
        Exit Sub 'if you want to exit when the value was found
    Else
        'You want to leave this empty and do what you want to do after the loop is done
        'and a match was not found
    End If
Loop Until Data.Cells(row, 1).Value = ""
'End of the loop.
'If the Sub gets to this point it means that the Value was not found at all after looping all the data.
'Enter below what to do if the value was not found
Data.Cells(row, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(17, 9).Value
Data.Cells(row, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(17, 12).Value 'Which Column has the name? I guessed 12

Exit Sub
```

I'm guessing this will work, however this is a very bad way to look for a value, instead you could use `Data.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Sheet1.Cells(17,9).Value)` and you dont have to loop a thing, I recommend doing a little reading/google searching on that approach before trying it that way.

Comment: I going to post more pictures on about wat im trying to do

Comment: i hope its clearer now

Comment: Also dados was a error while formulating the question the right one is Data

Comment: try the updated code above, review the last line to make sure it grabs the name with the proper column.

Comment: Thanks for ur time and ur teachings! ill look up the 'Data.Columns("").Find' method and try to do it in a way where i wont need a loop

Comment: Good luck and the more you learn the better. To a lot of people GoTo is "frowned upon" because if not properly done it can jump code that is needed later on, or a return may not be implemented properly. However GoTo is there for a reason, it can be a very good way to do Error Checking and other things, just not great in this case.